# How to copy table rows without knowing it's containing sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy data from one table to another, from one workbook to another.
I know the table names, they are identical.
The source table has an unknown number of data rows plus an unknown number of empty rows. The destination table (same name, same sheet) has only empty rows, but not necessarily the same overall number of rows as the origin.

i know i can do something like

```
sourceBook.Activate
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(knownTableName).DataBodyRange.Select
Selection.Copy
destinationBook.Activate
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(knownTableName).DataBodyRange.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

However there are a number of problems:

1. The table is not on the activeSheet. How do i find the sheet that the table is on? or is  there a better way to reference it (ideally without having to find the sheet first)?
2. I know `.Activate` and `Selection.Copy` is slow and bad. How can i do it better?
3. How do i find the "used" data range of both tables without looping through the table rows?
4. Is it possible to copy the data row by row (so that only non empty rows are copied)? ideally, i would like to just insert all non-empty source rows to the destination table and subsequently delete all empty rows in the destination table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer question 2:

```
Dim loSource as ListObject
Dim loDestination as ListObject

Set loSource = ...   'To do
Set loDestination = ...   'To do

loDestination.Range(2,1).Resize(loSource.ListRows.Count, loSource.ListColumns.Count).Value = loSource.DataBodyRange.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your first problem (maybe you could break your question up and ask different questions for different problems)

Since `ListObjects` is a child of `WorkSheet` -- I don't see of any way to avoid iterating through the workbooks looking for the sheet containing the table. Something like this:

```
Function FindTable(WB As Workbook, TableName As String) As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As String
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each ws In WB.Sheets
        wsName = ws.ListObjects(TableName).Parent.Name
    Next
    If Len(wsName) = 0 Then
        FindTable = "Table Not Found"
    Else
        FindTable = wsName
    End If
End Function
```

To test it I created a table named "Hidden Table" and put it on sheet 3. Then I ran this:

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print FindTable(ActiveWorkbook, "Hidden Table")
    Debug.Print FindTable(ActiveWorkbook, "Nonexistant Table")
End Sub
```

Which printed:

```
Sheet3
Table Not Found
```